# How to assign values to my java ArrayList properly?

Tags: java, arraylist

M is an ArrayList of Arraylists (2D ArrayList).
I have this code and what I want to do is assign the value "resp" to the variable "valor" in an specific position in M, but the instruction:

```
M.get(i).get(d).valor = resp;
```

assigns the value of "resp" to all of the Array positions, not only the one I want, which is in position `i`,`d`.
Why is this happening?

```
int d = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < f; i++){            
    resp = Leer.nextFloat();            
    M.get(i).get(d).valor = resp;
}
```

Comment: Because you're looping on the array list and changing all of its elements.

Comment: My guess is that valor is a static field, instead of being an instance field. Post the class containing this field. And please, respect the Java naming conventions, choose good names for your variables (like `matrix`, `row`, `column`, `rowLength`), and don't use public fields.

Comment: May be you have the same object instance in many positions in M.

Answer (score 0):

A For loop repeats the code inside its block until the condition fails.

Your condition is **i** *less than* **f**. Considering i = 0 and supposing **f** is the last element in the ArrayList of arrayLists then what your code does is:

Behind the scene this is what happens:

```
M.get(0).get(d).valor = resp;
M.get(1).get(d).valor = resp;
...
M.get(f-1).get(d).valor = resp;
```

Hence, you are editing all the values of the arrayList. If you know the positions exactly don't use a for loop. Insert number:
e.g. M.get(0).get(d).valor = resp;

If you do not know the position then:

int d = 5;

```
    int d = 5;
    for(int i=0;i<f;i++){            
        resp = Leer.nextFloat();
        if(M.get(i).get(d) == valor)
            M.get(i).get(d).valor = resp;
    }
```

If this is not what you meant, then post your whole code.

Comment: The thing is that I do want to edit all the values of the arrayList but assigning a different "resp" to each one (resp is read from keyboard). I run the program step by step and I notice that only one execution of M.get(i).get(d).valor = resp; assigns the same value to all the arraylists, without even entering to the for again.

Comment: @Setrakus you have to add the code for reading the input in the for loop too:
for(...)
{
     resp = in.readLine();
     M.get(i).get(d).valor = resp;
}